# Replace String with Random Characters While Preserving Formatting

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is there an easy way to replace the characters in a string while preserving a format?  For example, let's say I have a string holding a telephone number 111-222-3333.

I would like to change that number to a randomly generated number, but preserve the original format (both all numeric and the dashes).

So the random output may be something like: 720-190-6542

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, but it depends on what format you're trying to maintain. Most can be done through a [string replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) using [regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions). For your example, this should do the trick:

```
let number = "123-456-7890";
let numRegex = /\d/g; //this regex finds all instances of digits
let randomNumber = number.replace(
    numRegex,
  function(oldNum){ //function to choose what to replace found digits with
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 10); //randomly chooses an int from 0-9 for each replacement
});

console.log(randomNumber); //prints a random phone number
```

Answer (score 0):

use randomstring for numeric options:

```
const randomstring = require('randomstring');

let randomNumber = randomstring.generate(options = {
      length: 10,
      charset: 'numeric'
    });

String.prototype.splice = function(indx, rem, str) {
   return this.slice(0, indx) + str + this.slice(indx + Math.abs(rem));
};

var result = randomNumber.toString().splice(3,0,"-").splice(7,0,"-");
```